# PayPal response to PDT POST-back

Tags: php, paypal

I have been studying the PayPal documentation on Payment Data Transfer (PDT). I am confused on one point in particular:

After I send back the POST containing the transaction ID and PDT token, the documentation says PayPal send back a response and the first line of this response id either SUCCESS or FAIL. What is confusing me is

a) what URL is that response sent to (I assume it is the same URL the original GET response is sent to) and

b) in what form is this response sent to me? Is it GET or POST or something else?

Also, is there someplace I can find example code in PHP for this sequence of transactions?

For reference, the PayPal document I'm looking at is:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/

Thanks for your help,
Ken

Answer (score 1):

You probably already figured this one out by now, but it might help others.

a) Your assumption is correct. Usually, you would build your POST request to Paypal using Curl, and analyse the response in the same script.

b) It's POST, in my opinion, you will just get in in the Curl response.

> Also, is there someplace I can find example code in PHP for this sequence of transactions?

Yes, PDT code samples here: https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples

IPN code samples here: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples